# Why a separately defined function does not work on a "domready" event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, domready

I am quite new to JavaScript. I am trying to set equal heights to some elements. I managed to do everything except moving the function outside the "addEvent" declaration.

In other words, this code works:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {  
    var elements = $$( 'div#leftcolumn div.module_menu' );  
    if( elements && elements.length > 1 ) {  
        var heights = [];  
        elements.each( function( el ) {  
            heights.push( el.getStyle('height').toInt() );  
        });
        maxHeight = Math.max.apply( Math, heights ) + "px";
        elements.each( function( el ) {
            el.setStyle('height', maxHeight );
        });
        delete(heights);  
    }
}
);
```

while this code does NOT work:

```
function matchHeight( selector ) { 
var elements = $$( selector );  
if( elements && elements.length > 1 ) {  
    var heights = [];  
    elements.each( function( el ) {  
        heights.push( el.getStyle('height').toInt() );  
    });
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply( Math, heights ) + "px";
    elements.each( function( el ) {
        el.setStyle('height', maxHeight );
    });
    delete(heights);  
  }
}
window.addEvent( 'domready', matchHeight( 'div#leftcolumn div.module_menu' ) );
```

I already test with simpler functions and it works, like e.g:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() { alert('test'); } )
```

is equivalent to

```
function giveMessage() { alert('test'); }
window.addEvent( 'domready', giveMessage())
```

why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you need to remove the parenthesis; a function is an object, and you need to pass the function, not its return value. So, for your first example, you should have:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() { matchHeight('div#leftcolumn div.module_menu'); } );
```

Instead. For your second example, it's:

```
function giveMessage() { alert('test'); }
window.addEvent( 'domready', giveMessage)
```

Again, you pass the object `giveMessage`, not the result obtained after invoking it.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put your `matchHeight` call in a closure. Change your last line to:

```
window.addEvent( 'domready', function(){matchHeight( 'div#leftcolumn div.module_menu' )} );
```

Answer (score 1):

K so that link is looking for a pointer to the function.  When you pass it an anonymous function (as in eg #1) that function is created/stored in memory, and that location is passed in.  Your second case though, JS executes the function (because of your brackets+arguments) and then passes the result as the pointer... which isn't want you want.

What you'd need to do instead is:

```
function setup() {
  matchHeight( 'div#leftcolumn div.module_menu');
}
window.addEvent('domready',setup);
```

Or still use an anonymous function:

```
window.addEvent('domready',
  function() {matchHeight( 'div#leftcolumn div.module_menu');});
```

FWIW `window.addEvent` isn't totally cross-browser compatible, see also [window.attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)